# Why does the the break line still allow for String item = sc.nextLine(); to be executed but the subsequent conditional arguments to be ignored?

Tags: java, for-loop

```
import java.util.*;

public class PeaImproved {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String rightStore = null;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int restaurants = sc.nextInt(); 
        sc.nextLine(); 
        
        for (int i = 0; i < restaurants; i++) {
            int menuLength = sc.nextInt(); 
            sc.nextLine();
            String restaurantName = sc.nextLine(); 
            boolean[] hasRequiredItems = {false, false};

            for (int j = 0; j < menuLength; j++) {
                String item = sc.nextLine();
                
                if (item.equals("pea soup")) {
                    hasRequiredItems[0] = true;
                }
                
                if (item.equals("pancakes")) {
                    hasRequiredItems[1] = true;
                }

                if (hasRequiredItems[0] && hasRequiredItems[1]) {
                    rightStore = restaurantName;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        
        if (rightStore != null) {
            System.out.println(rightStore);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Anywhere is fine I guess");
        }
    }
}
```

I expected the inner for loop to be completely executed. This is the whole problem:

The first line of input contains a number n, the number of restaurants. Then follow the n restaurant menus. Each menu starts with a line containing a number k, the number of menu items for the day. The remainder of the menu consists of k+1 lines, each containing a nonempty string of at most
100 characters. The first of these lines is the restaurant name, and the rest are menu items. Strings consist only of lower case letters ‘a’-‘z’ and spaces, and they always start and end with a letter. All restaurant names are unique.

Output
Output a single line. If at least one restaurant has both “pea soup” and “pancakes” as menu items, output the name of the first of those restaurants, by the order in which the restaurants appear in the input. Otherwise, output “Anywhere is fine I guess”.

Comment: `break` works the way you expect it to. There must be something else wrong in your code. You should use the debugger in your IDE to find out what that is. I'd start by considering why the inner loop has two different ways to end: The counter, and the `break`.

Comment: It might be practical to share some input and provide the expected output. Then, it will be much easier to determine what wrong with the code.

Comment: The problem is that `break;` only stops reading menu items for the *current* restaurant.  It exists the inner loop, but then the outer loop continues.  Therefore, if a menu contains "pea soup" and "pancakes" followed by other menu items, the next call to `int menuLength = sc.nextInt();` will try to interpret a menu item as if it were an int.  Perhaps after the inner loop completes, you should check the value of `rightStore`?

Answer (score -1):

Remove sc.nextLine() as shown below since it's not required, it works as you expected.

```
    String rightStore = null;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int restaurants = sc.nextInt();
    //sc.nextLine();

    for (int i = 0; i < restaurants; i++)
    {
        int menuLength = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        String restaurantName = sc.nextLine();
        boolean[] hasRequiredItems = { false, false };

        for (int j = 0; j < menuLength; j++)
        {
            String item = sc.nextLine();

            if (item.equals("pea soup"))
            {
                hasRequiredItems[0] = true;
            }

            if (item.equals("pancakes"))
            {
                hasRequiredItems[1] = true;
            }

            if (hasRequiredItems[0] && hasRequiredItems[1])
            {
                rightStore = restaurantName;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (rightStore != null)
    {
        System.out.println(rightStore);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Anywhere is fine I guess");
    }
```